# Find and render user from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

A little background. I am sending a post with the username. About what he came to me is displayed in the log.

```
console.log(req.body.username); // 'username'
```

How do I use mongodb to find and render a user with a username from the post?

For example, the sample and render of all users looks like this, but I still do not understand how to get the one I need

```
exports.profile = function(req, res, next){

User.find(function(err,users){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.render('users/profile',{  users:users });
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
exports.profile = function(req, res, next){

User.find({username: req.body.username}function(err,users){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.render('users/profile',{  users:users });
});}
```

and here you have some docs to read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) function to find.

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.username}.function(err,users){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.render('users/profile',{  users:users });
    });}
```